# Handling multiple users' content and logging out for a messaging app (data protection related)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm sorry if this is a dupe, but I'm getting to the point now in development on thinking about how should I solve this scenario (pretty common I think for social based apps).

I have a messaging app that I'm writing. I'm wanting to store all of the message's content for the specified username in their own folder in the NSDocument directory. Example: jdoe55 would have a subdirectory in the NSDocument directory named "jdoe55" as this is a unique username that is registered on the server side when the user first signs up.

The next part, when jdoe55 logs out and he lets his friend with the username "maryDoe46" log into her account using HIS phone, I know I will have to create another subdirectory for her message content, but how would I truly protect this data so others can't see it? When maryDoe46 logs out, her stuff should never be visible or accessible in the app to jdoe55. Also, this data shouldnt be iTunes or iExplorer readable is my hopes.

I'm just trying to figure this mess out, and I appreciate any help offered!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using NSDocument instead of Core Data?  Also, it doesn't look like NSDocument is available for iOS development.  According to the docs, it's available in "OS X v10.0 and later."  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: CoreData, meh! I really didn't plan on fooling with it. Edit: it's NSDocumentDirectory (I didnt type it all)

Comment: It looks like you can put permissions on the file when you create it.  Saying that, I wasn't able to find anything that would block iTunes/iExplorer access.  My advice would be to make the directory/files hidden and encrypt the data within those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't store the content on the device** at all, if you can help it. Mary probably doesn't want Joe syncing his device with his computer and then digging through her content. A messaging app isn't much use without a connection to the server, and messages are small, so it's easy to just load the user's content from the server when they log in.

If you must store messages on the device, why do you need a whole directory for each user? One would think that a single file (encrypted, please) per user would be sufficient, and a lot easier than having to open dozens of files just to get all the previous messages.

Comment: Don't assume it's a standard run of the mill messaging app, there's alot of non text content that can't be simply downloaded every time you log-in to the app. Let's say each "message" has a max size of 3-4 MB depending on what they do. I'll look into that single file method, I just thought it would be more logical to have sub-directories for the sake of developing, even if those subdirectories are encrypted.